# Defining SplashScreen Theme in Jetpack Compose without XML

Tags: android, kotlin, android-splashscreen

I've been exploring Jetpack Compose to create my Android app UI, and I want to implement a SplashScreen using the Android SplashScreen API. Jetpack Compose encourages the use of Kotlin code over XML, which I appreciate. However, when defining the SplashScreen theme, it seems that all the examples available online still use XML code for define SplashScreen theme like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_splash</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.TixCompose</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My goal is to create the SplashScreen theme entirely in Kotlin code without relying on XML. Is there a proper way to define the SplashScreen theme using only Kotlin code with Jetpack Compose? If so, could you provide an example or guide me on how to do this?

My current Theme.kt

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun MainTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You have to use Both XML and Kotlin Theme File Code. Only Kotlin Code I think is not possible for a now. because Compose Official Sample Also Uses XML theme.